# Typescript find does not recognize the returned type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am simply looking up an object in an array, but typescript thinks the return type is undefined.

```
 let b =  serverResponse.hotels.find(h => h.hotelMoniker == offer.hotelMoniker) ;
 console.log(b);
 newVacation.hotel = b //Error Here
```

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/app/services/room.service.ts:170:7 
>       TS2322: Type 'HotelResultsModel | undefined' is not assignable to type 'HotelResultsModel'.

When I hover over the variables, typescript thinks the objects in the serverResponse.hotels array are of the type 'HotelResultsModel'.  I can even log them to the console.

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HotelResultsModel'.

I there a way to tell Typescript to ignore the error or cast the find result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no *b* found. Try this:

```
let b =  serverResponse.hotels.find(h => h.hotelMoniker == offer.hotelMoniker) ;
newVacation.hotel = b || null;
```

Comment: Thanks Faly, I got it to work.  Using this: `newVacation.hotel = b || new HotelResultsModel();`  The b object did have valid values, so the code did pickup the b value, but with the new object declaration, it worked.  Thank you.